# Jquery: execute function without event

Tags: jquery

I want to execute some functions on a selected element `$(selected)`, using `this` as the selector.

```
$(external).click(function(){
  //relevant code below
  $(selected).????(){
    console.log($(this).html()); //i.e.
    console.log($(this).height()); //i.e.
  }
});
```

Basically, I don't know what to put for in place of ???? above. Any ideas?

Edits * reworded question, and added sample code for clarity.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
      //code to be fired on page load
    });

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean just executing a JavaScript function or do you mean execute a function on a set of elements returned from a jquery selector?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? When do you want your function to be executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after `.each()`

```
$(external).click(function(){
  //relevant code below
  $(selected).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); //i.e.
    console.log($(this).height()); //i.e.
  });
});
```

Doc:
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 9):

If you want to execute a function after the page is loaded with jquery you can do it like

```
$(function(){
    //code
});
```

Or if you want it executed right away:

```
(function(){
    //code
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using external as the element:

```
<div id="external">
    <div id="internal">
        inner
    </div>
</div>
```

Then for original element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var external = $("#external");
    external.click(function(){
      var selected = $(this);
        console.log(selected.html()); //i.e.
        console.log(selected.height()); //i.e.
      });
});
```

Or element contained within:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var external = $("#external");
    external.click(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find("#internal");
        console.log(selected.html()); //i.e.
        console.log(selected.height()); //i.e.
      });
});
```